# Criação de botões com bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

1. Preciso criar botões com o estilo bootstrap semelhante a imagem abaixo.
   Pode-se encontrar os botões: https://fontawesome.com/

[image]

2. Entretanto consigo chegar somente neste resultado:

[image]

1. Utilizo o seguinte código:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">


<a class="btn btn-large btn-danger" href="#">
  <i class="fa fa-user-friends fa-3x"></i>
  TESTE
</a>
```

3. Gostaria apenas de colocar o ícone acima e a escrita abaixo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basta usar as classes flex originais do Bootstrap, nem precisa de CSS extra pra isso. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/

OBS: use as classes do grid do Bootstrap tb para não ter problemas como, `container > row > col` logicamente vc vai precisar definir quantas `col-x` por linha vc quer e como vai quebra-las conforme a tela for diminuindo com `col-md-x` e `col-sm-x` etc https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-2">
        <a class="btn btn-large btn-danger m-2 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center" href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-user-friends fa-3x"></i>
            <span>TESTE</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
        <a class="btn btn-large btn-danger m-2 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center" href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-user-friends fa-3x"></i>
            <span>TESTE</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
        <a class="btn btn-large btn-danger m-2 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center" href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-user-friends fa-3x"></i>
            <span>TESTE</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
        <a class="btn btn-large btn-danger m-2 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center" href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-user-friends fa-3x"></i>
            <span>TESTE</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
        <a class="btn btn-large btn-danger m-2 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center" href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-user-friends fa-3x"></i>
            <span>TESTE</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
        <a class="btn btn-large btn-danger m-2 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center" href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-user-friends fa-3x"></i>
            <span>TESTE</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
        <a class="btn btn-large btn-danger m-2 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center" href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-user-friends fa-3x"></i>
            <span>TESTE</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Cheguei a um resultado parecido usando card

```
<div class="card">
        <a class="btn btn-large btn-danger" href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-user-friends fa-3x"></i>
        </a>
        <div class="card-footer">
            TESTE
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Vou te mostrar um exemplo bem simples:

[Imagem com botão semelhante ao da foto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBOD4.jpg)

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <style>
      a, button{ margin: 5px}
    </style>


    <div class="form-group row "><a href="https://minhavenda.com.br/carrinho" class="btn btn-secondary col-3" style="
        padding: 0px;
    "> <i class="fa fa-2x fa-backspace p-3">
        
    </i><span class="d-block" style="
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        width: 100%;
    ">Voltar 
    </span></a> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-3" style="
        padding: 0px;
    "><i class="fa fa-2x fa-save p-3">
        
    </i><span class="d-block" style="
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        width: 100%;
    ">Salvar
    </span></button>
    
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger col-3" style="
        padding: 0px;
    "><i class="fa fa-2x fa-trash p-3">
        
    </i><span class="d-block" style="
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        width: 100%;
    ">Excluir
    </span></button>
    </div>
```

Pronto espero que goste!

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).